# Public Static IP for Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

Is there any ways to assign **public static IP for Azure VM**? Do I have to do through the Azure Virtual Network or I need to do it when setting up the VM?

Would appreciate that if somebody could provide me some tutorial and steps to achieve it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - but only recently. Run `get-help *-AzureReservedIP*` to get all the cmdlets you need.

Here is more:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: use the "**New-AzureReservedIP**" powershell cmdlet in the VM

the verbose syntax looks like this:

```
New-AzureReservedIP – ReservedIPName “MyWebsiteIP” –Label “WebsiteIP” –Location “Japan West”
```

for more information, here's a relevant blog post about it:

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

here's an msdn spec on it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn769136.aspx