# Azure VM Public IP

Tags: azure, windows-server-2008

I have provisioned an Azure Virtual Machine with Windows Server 2008, but I now need a **public static IP** for it (for support purposes).

Is this something that exists by default or do I have to configure it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has previously been discussed:

[Public Static IP for Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23901808/public-static-ip-for-azure-vm)

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip/

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/ip-addresses/

Hopefully one of those links gives you the answer you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I just was not sure how up-to-date those answers are.

Comment: When you start-up a VM it gets assigned an IP address based on the host the VM is on. This can only change when the machine is stopped and dealocated, but it is possible and does happen. From what I can see it is  £0.0025 per hour per IP (~£2/month per IP).

Comment: This page has information on the costs: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/ip-addresses/ and how to get them.

Answer (score 1):

there is no direct process from azure management portal to set a static IP for service or VM, but you can do it from Azure-Powershell
Here are some links

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/05/14/reserved-ip-addresses/

https://systemcenterpoint.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/assigning-a-public-reserved-ip-to-existing-azure-cloud-service/